# Weight distribution of human on one foot in middle of plywood

Tags: structural-engineering, load-spreading

Question: If a 300 lb uniform load is distributed over 24 inch^2 (estimated area of foot), and I add a 6x6 3/4" plywood centered underneath this uniform load, what is the remaining load carried by the same 24 inch^2 area, versus how much of it has been distributed to the rest of the plywood?

Background: One of my upstairs neighbours is very heavy. His bedroom is right above ours. The floor of his bedroom squeaks intensely, but only when he is walking on them. Other people in his family who have a smaller weight do not cause it to squeak. It seems like his weight causes the subfloor to deflect past a certain threshold that causes the squeaking. I don't have the money to replace the subfloor and have tried screwing down the floorboards. I am thinking of laying plywood sheets on his floor and covering with carpet. I am hoping that this will distribute his weight enough that the deflection threshold will not be reached. I believe I need to decrease the uniform load under the surface of his foot by 30% to prevent squeaking based on the fact that another person weighing 30% less does not cause the squeaking.

Comment: What are the structural details and dimensions of the subfloor?

Comment: The squeaking sound comes from the wood board joints due to deflection, it can't be eliminated by localized strengthening. You need a structural engineer or experienced flooring contractor to evaluate and provide better solutions.

Comment: @GregLocock joists are 9"x2" rough sawn @ 16" OC, spanning 14 feet, overlaid with perpendicular 3/4" x 6" pine planks, tar paper, then 2" oak hardwood floor.

Comment: @r13 I am aware of what is causing the squeaks, and how to fix it correctly ($$$). My _engineering_ question is whether depositing plywood on top of the hardwood floor (not secured in any way, not aimed as a structural fix of any kind, but strategically placed so that the center of plywood is in the high-traffic area) will reduce the subfloor deflection caused by someone walking on it, and therefore the squeaks. I have empirical evidence that 180 lbs / 24 inch^2 does not cause squeaks while 300 lbs / 24 inch^2 does cause them. Will 3/4" plywood allow me to distribute the load sufficiently?

Comment: Well yes, you've roughly doubled (or more, consider using Silicone RTV to glue it round the edges) the stiffness, so by your observation it might work, if it is simply the floorboards that are involved. That is it is a reasonable plan but there is no guarantee it'll work..

Comment: Sorry, don't want to waste your money and time on a short-lived fix, no more suggestions.